# Generate a PDF from HTML template using WKWebview

Tags: swift, pdf, wkwebview

We have functionality in an existing app, have to generate a pdf and it should be printable in the A4. The PDF is almost 8 to 10 pages

**I have applied below solution:**

Loading the HTML template on the WKwebview and doing a few operations on the content and converting it into a pdf.

1. Converting the HTML into a string
2. Replacing a few data with dynamic content

**Issue:**

The solutions worked fine in the previous OS(14.5,15.5,16.1), it is not working on the latest os 16.6

The Table background CSS is not Rendering. I have tried both Inline and external CSS loading but still facing the same issue.

It seems the issue is with UIGraphics or WKwebview formaters.

could you please help me to resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMS2H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxVih.png)

**Approch1:**

func createPDF(formmatter: UIViewPrintFormatter, filename: String) -> String { let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "This is a test", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])

```
let printFormatter = UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(attributedText: attributedString)

let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()

render.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)





// 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

//let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()

render.addPrintFormatter(formmatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)



// 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi

let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)

//let printable = page.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10));



render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")

render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")



// 4. Create PDF context and draw

let pdfData = NSMutableData()

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)



for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {



    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()

    render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)

}



UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();



// 5. Save PDF file

var dst = self.getDestinationPath(1)

if dst.contains("file://") {

    dst = dst.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")

}



//let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(filename).pdf"

pdfData.write(toFile: dst, atomically: true)

print("open \(dst)")



return dst
```

}
}

**Approach2:**

But the pdf is Generating in a single page not multiple and it's not printable using the below solution.

func createPDFMethod(webView: WKWebView, title:String="samplepdf"){
let pdfConfiguration = WKPDFConfiguration()

/// Using `webView.scrollView.frame` allows us to capture the
// entire page, not just the visible portion
pdfConfiguration.rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)

webView.createPDF(configuration: pdfConfiguration) { result in
switch result {
case .success(let data):
// Creates a path to the downloads directory

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let resourceDocPath = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
        let pdfNameFromUrl = "\(title).pdf"
        let actualPath = resourceDocPath.appendingPathComponent(pdfNameFromUrl)
        do {
            try data.write(to: actualPath, options: .atomic)
            print("pdf successfully saved!")
        } catch {
            print("Pdf could not be saved")
        }
    }

case .failure(let failure):
    print(failure.localizedDescription)
}
```

}
}